# Windows: create a multi-mouse lib that dose not require an UI

Tags: c#, windows, input, unity-game-engine, hid

I'm trying to create a windows application that can manage multiple mouses, with the feature of understanding which device is generating the input
(something like Microsoft's Multimouse, but without a UI).

The problem is that I don't want to use a UI because this will be a plug-in for Unity3D so I have many limitations imposed from this.

I also thought about a parallel service that can talk with Unity, but in that case I would like to not block all the system to take mouses inputs.
In this special case I have to manage 12 of these devices: [AimTrak](http://www.ultimarc.com/aimtrak_module.html), that are recognized as a mouse input device.
So does anyone have some idea about that how can do this without hacking them and rewriting their driver?

Answer (score -1):

Ok after 3 days of googleing things i have found a way to do this!!!!
We have need to make a windows's system hook on user32.dll in order to catch all mouse inputs.